# Java: I/O, read() will not fill buffer?

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, buffer

I am learning about I/O, Files and Sockets and i don't understand the meaning of this sentence

> read will not always fill a buffer

What does it mean? Anyone has some explanation for me?

Comment: I have no idea why, but it added the "homework" tag, just to clarify this, this is not a homework question, i just wanted to expand my knowledge and my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read() method accepts a byte-array that it will fill with from the stream or reader.

If there is not enough data available to fill the buffer, it can either

- wait until enough data is available
- return immediately but only provide the available data without filling the buffer completely.

The standard implementation does a mixtures of both: It waits until at least one byte is available.

Note: The second case implies that read() may return without any data at all.

Comment: It does neither of those things. It blocks until *at least one* byte is available, and returns the counted bytes actually read. See the Javadoc for InputStream.read(). -1

Answer (score 2):

```
"read will not always fill a buffer"
```

The above sentence means that `Buffer` has a certain `size` which is **AutoFlushed when filled,** But suppose the data to be **read into the Buffer is not enough to fill the Buffer**... Then you **need to manually flush it.**

For futher details read the `SCJP Programmer guide` by Kathy Sierra or `Thinking in Java's` **IO chapter**.

Comment: Thank you, well explained, this answer is as good as the other one i received here :)

Comment: There is no such operation as flushing an input buffer. -1

Answer (score 1):

It will block until at least one byte is available, and return the number of bytes that can be read at that point without blocking again. See the Javadoc.